# Core Data migration to iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, core-data-migration

I have a Core Data application, which uses NSSQLiteStoreType as a persistent store. This app is already in AppStore. And now i have to add iCloud support for Data syncing.

Please, give me a documentation link or a tutorial on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the WWDC videos from 2011 and 2012 that talk about iCloud and Core Data.  They have some good explanations of the basics, and should get you well on your way.  They are available on apple's dev website, to anyone who has a paid developer subscription.